# React Image path is correct but it doesn't find/import it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, import

I have images in one folder while one of the images is getting imported easily the second one isn't being found

```js
import img from '../Img/a292.jpg';
// import img from '../Img/building5.png';

export default function First() {
    return (
        <section id="first" className="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <img src={img} alt="img"/>
        </section>
    )
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

[My screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aqgwa.png)

[when importing building5.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKYtK.jpg)

[when importing a292.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xv9wq.png)

EDIT: Things I have tried `src={require('../Img/a292.jpg')}` and I have tried to convert the image to `png` because all the PNG-s were working so I thought it's the format that meters,but no didn't work :/

Comment: try import demo_image from '../Img/a292.jpg'; and then change the src to demo_image

Comment: Nope, didn't work :/

Comment: Could you show the folder structure?

Comment: It's the first Image 'My screen'

Comment: Try src={require('../Img/building5.png')}}

Comment: Building is working the one that's not working is a292.jpg I even converted it to png and I have tried require, didn't help :////

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an exotic solution, It's happening very rarely but it might happen to you, Change the name to numbers like 123.jpg
It might happen that the letter a is in Russian and English or something like that, just try

Comment: Oooh it worked thanks, Yeah the letter a was in other language maybe :/

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've faced the same issue and I do the following to import images:

- Place the image a292.jpg in Public folder.
- Now you can directly write in the img src the path as './a292.jpg'. [The path is relative to the Public folder because index.html is present in public folder so when the virtual DOM is rendered it takes the relative path from index.html]